# Suddenly found bugs when using git

Tags: git

When I switch my git to a branch doing a change, I suddenly found a bug that I need to fix.
What should I do?
Do I need to record the bug in a excel or piece of paper then fix it in another branch?
If that is the case, I think git is stupid.

Comment: Where *is* the bug? And where do you want to fix it? And ***why*** did you think of Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got your question right, you need `git stash`, e.g.

```
# I have some uncommited changes!
git stash
# now I have a clean working directory, without the uncommited changes. 
# fix Your bug, commit push, etc.
git stash pop
# now my uncommited changes are back! Keep working on the feature
```

Comment: If I use git stash, would I delete all my changes for the branch? I want to keep my change and fix the bug.

Comment: I'd argue you shouldn't work on the fix in the branch where you work on a change. You should checkout a new branch to fix the bug. And if you're switching branches `git stash` is less convenient that just committing current changes to the first branch and appending this commit with `git commit -a` when you come back.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to fix it in another branch, then create a new clone and fix it in there.

Comment: There is no need to create a new clone. This is an ordinary scenario and git enables you to manage it without having a second clone.

Comment: There is no _need_ - it might just be _easier_.